# Synchronous WAV playback in NAudio

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I'm making a game music player in C# based on `NAudio`. The original PCM-16 four-channel audio file (Wii AST) is brought into the application, and the channels are split into two separate stereo wav files. I have a slider in my application to allow you to fade between the two files, because each pair of channels from the original AST file contains a different part/version of the song.

I'm using two instances of `WaveOut` and `AudioFileReader` for the two wave files to play them back, and I have a trackbar in the application to adjust the "channel bias" (in other words, the volume of the WaveOut instances). My problem is that a lot of the time (especially when seeking using the trackbar), the two audio files end up playing out-of-sync. I can't seem to get them to play at the exact same time. Does anyone know how to get the files to play in sync?

The only solution I can think of is to convert the two split files into a single 4-channel wave file so you could just adjust the volume of the channel pairs and not have to worry about syncing, but `NAudio` doesn't seem to have a way to do that.

Please keep in mind that I am new to asking questions on StackOverflow, so if I need to provide more detail or if there was something I failed to explain, please let me know. And please, *be constructive*.

Thanks!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out, I completely overlooked a class in `NAudio` that mixes multiple audio streams together. What I ended up doing was creating an instance of `MixingWaveProvider32` at the beginning of the program and initializing it when the audio files were created by the decoder to prepare for playback. Here was the final code I came up with that ended up working:

```
MixingWaveProvider32 mixingWaveProvider32;
WaveOut masterOut;
AudioFileReader audioFileReader;
AudioFileReader audioFileReader2;
...

void loadAstFile(string path)
{
    string stream1_Path = path + "_c1.wav";
    string stream2_Path = path + "_c2.wav";

    DisposeAudioFileReaders();

    AstReader astReader = new AstReader(path);
    if(astReader.Channels == 4)
    {
        astReader.Export(stream1_Path, 1.0f);
        astReader.Export(stream2_Path, 0.0f);
        audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(stream1_Path);
        audioFileReader2 = new AudioFileReader(stream2_Path);
        mixingWaveProvider32 = new MixingWaveProvider32(new IWaveProvider[] { audioFileReader, audioFileReader2 });
    }
    else
    {
        astReader.Export(stream1_Path, 1.0f);
        audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(stream1_Path);
        audioFileReader.Volume = 1.0f;
        mixingWaveProvider32 = new MixingWaveProvider32(new IWaveProvider[] { audioFileReader});
    }

    masterOut = new WaveOut();
    masterOut.Init(mixingWaveProvider32);
    masterOut.Volume = 1.0f;
    
    RefreshComponents();
    Play();
}
```

Hopefully this helps somebody out there!